# Is there a way to stop arguments being formatted onto a new line each in VS Code?

Tags: visual-studio-code

A few days ago, I was looking through settings on VS Code. Without thinking, I changed a couple of settings. All of which were for the better, except for one. For some reason, whenever I save, each argument within brackets is put onto a new line (I use auto-format on save).

Here is the code before:

[image: before]

and after

[image: after].

For the life of me I can't find the setting anywhere. I'm begging to believe that it's not a setting and something to do with me making some JavaScript files, considering it's formatted the same just with () instead of {}.

Answer (score 0):

I think this may be caused by an unstable plugin affecting the formatting of the code. Remove untrusted plugins from Visual Studio Code Editor. Then try using common code formatter tools like [Prettier](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=esbenp.prettier-vscode).

If the problem is not resolved, do a clean install of Visual Studio Code Editor. For a clean install, you need to manually delete the following directories. For a clean install, you need to manually delete the following directories after removing the Visual Studio Code Editor from your system. In this way, all your settings and add-ons will be removed from your system. Then you can fix this problem by installing a stable version of Visual Studio Code Editor.

```
%UserProfile%\.vscode
%AppData%\Code
%LocalAppData%\Programs\Microsoft VS Code
```